# MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException after building with maven shade plugin

Tags: java, json, maven, jersey

Hi I'm building a java REST client application that uses json. There's a conflict in my dependencies: one essential dependency requires jackson databind/core/annotations 2.10.1, another essential dependency uses an older version 2.2.2.

When running the app in Eclipse, this led to a `MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException`. The problem was that maven included version 2.2.2 instead of 2.10.1. So I use dependency management to resolve the conflict and include version 2.10.1. Within Eclipse this solved the issue and the app runs fine.

But after building the app with the maven shade plugin, the standalone app still fails with the `MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException`. The exception is thrown in a part of the code requiring version 2.10.1, not in the part depending on version 2.2.2.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I checked my local maven repository and it only contains version 2.10.1. So the problem is not that the jar somehow still includes version 2.2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Running the app within Eclipse apparently doesn't require explicitly registering a `JacksonJsonProvider`, but running the standalone app does:

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig().connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider()).register(new JacksonJsonProvider());
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().withConfig(config) ...
```